# Adding custom view to RelativeLayout in code: LayoutParams ignored / custom views not positioned correctly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I face the following situation:

- I have a `DialogFragment` with a custom layout that will contain several Views that are dynamically inserted.
- Most of these Views are custom Views.

The DialogFragment's custom layout's parent container is a `RelativeLayout`.

**TL;DR**

- I have a DialogFragment with a custom layout
- Custom views that are added with `addView(customView, params)` where `params` have been defined with `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastComponent.getId());`
- They are not placed below `lastComponent`. Also, any other rule is ignored, while it's working for core `TextView`s.

**Popup.onCreateView()**

- Custom layout for the dialog is inflated
- PopupComponents (the custom view that needs to be added to the dialog) are added to the dialog View
- IDs for these components are set
- The component n gets `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with `(RelativeLayout.BELOW, [n-1].getId())`

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_stickerfound, container, false); // is a RelativeLayout
      RelativeLayout vg = (RelativeLayout) rootView;

      // ...

      // Save the last component to align the next one below it
      View lastComponent = null;
      int idIndex = 1;

      // Render title if it is set
      if(title != null) {
          TextView tvTitle = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
          tvTitle.setText(title);

          // Set an ID for layouting
          int id = idIndex++;
          if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
              id = View.generateViewId();
          }

          tvTitle.setId(id);
          lastComponent = tvTitle;

          // Add title to our layout
          vg.addView(tvTitle, titleParams);
      }

      // Get the component (shortened for simplicity, iterator is set and all working)
      PopupComponent pc = iterator.next();

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      if(lastComponent != null) {
          params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastComponent.getId());
      }         

      // Give the view a dynamically created ID for layouting reasons
      int id = idIndex++;
      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
          id = View.generateViewId();
      }
      if(pc.getId() == 0) {
          pc.setId(id);
      }

      // Attach the component to the popup and apply the layout params.
      pc.setLayoutParams(params);
      vg.addView(pc, params);

      lastComponent = pc;
      i++;
  ```

`vg.addView(pc, params)` did not work. The following shows the result, but does not match the code above (there is an extra `TextView` added - I'll get into that later on):
[[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGiur.jpg)

---

I tried another solution: inflating the layout and defining the root view doing so:

**PopupComponent.attachTo(Context context, ViewGroup container)**

```
public View attachTo(Context context, ViewGroup container) {
    //View v =  View.inflate(context, layoutRes,
      //      container);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = li.inflate(layoutRes, container, false);

    insertData();

    return v;
}
```

**Popup.onCreateView()**

```
// see the end of the snippet above 
// Attach the component to the popup and apply the layout params.
pc.attachTo(getActivity().getBaseContext(), vg);
```

But that also failed, giving me an empty result:
[Screenshot2] < left out because I have less than 10 reputation, whoops. Might add it in the comments?

---

If I set attachToRoot to true in `li.inflate(layoutRes, container, false)` -> `li.inflate(layoutRes, container, true)` the custom components are visible, but the LayoutParams seem to be ignored:
[[Screenshot3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omf0X.jpg)

The odd thing is, it's working for the `TextView(s)` at the beginning (I've only described one in code, there are actually two for testing purposes). So, shouldn't my custom `View`s be handled like a `TextView` that's also "not very different" to a View?

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

U can use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` to  add view one below another. And set orientation to LinearLayout.

Comment: Well... Indeed, that solves the problem, thanks. But what if I want to add another view thats aligned right to another view? For now, I'm fine with LinearLayout, but for the future I might want to use RelativeLayout for the flexibility it gives me in comparison to LinearLayout. Or is that a bad approach in general?

Comment: That first seemed to solve it, but it does not work with `vg.addView(pc, params)`. The views do not seem to be added, and with my `attachTo(ViewGroup parent)` method (see my question, snippet 2) the programmatically set layout params as well as the attributes in the respective layout xml are ignored.

Comment: if u want use realtivelayout u need to set id for each view and use rule to align it right or left or top or bottom.. If this answer is useful mark as correct and upvote it...